# Laravel - Save on multiple models/relationships

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, relational-database

I have 3 models: User, Campagin, CampaginType

- **User** has many **Campagin**
- **Campagin** belongs to **CampaginType**

(**User** does not related with **CampaginType**)

When I save a campaign (contains `user_id` and `campaign_type_id` field), how can I save 2 fields with a single command.

I try like:
`$user->campaigns()->campaignType($campaignType)->create($campaignInfo);`

But It not work! :(

Comment: in laravel you don't save fields! you fulfill them, then save the whole model.

Comment: what does campaignType($campaignType) supposed to do? Have you declared it somewhere?

Comment: can you show us your model implementation?

Comment: You should fill campaign_type_id to CampainInfo before saving. 
For example:
 $campainInfo->campaign_type_id = $campainType->id ;
 $user->campaigns()->create($campaignInfo);

I'll save in to DB with one query, I think.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Campaign::create($request->all());
    $campaign = Campaign::where('unique_field', '=', $request->uniquefield)->first();
    $campaign->users()->attach($request->user_id);
    $campaign->campaign_type()->attach($request->campaign_type_id);

    return redirect('your_destination_view');
}
```

**Note**

`uniquefield` is something that is unique to your campaign database table. You should also modify the models by adding the respective methods to make the eloquent relationship.